# Changing the labels in histogram when using lapply() or walk() to produce histogram

Tags: r, histogram, lapply, axis-labels

I am trying to create a matrix of several histograms using lapply() or walk() - from the purrr-package.

This is a fabricated version of my data set including only 5 of 11 columns and 3 of about 100 rows:

| pid | gender | Rand | BP | GH | VT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F | D | 5 | 7 | 5 |
| 2 | M | A | 6 | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | F | D | 0 | 30 | 5 |

This is the code I'm using and were I would like to add something to change the x-label depending on the i-value.

```
    x <- datf #dataframe
    u <- x[,4:11]
    par(mfrow=c(2,4)) 
        walk(x[,4:11], 
                 function(i) 
                      {hist(i[x$rand=="D"], 
                            col=rgb(0,0,1,0.2), 
                            main = "Histogram of score",
                            ylim=c(0,100))
                        hist(i[x$rand=="A"], 
                            col=rgb(1,0,0,0.2), 
                            add=TRUE)})
```

Instead of walk() I have used lapply() - but to hide the output in the Rmarkdown document changed to walk().

I have tried to use `xlab = paste(colnames(i))` and `xlab = paste(colnames(u))`, after reading similar questions; [Using lapply on a dataframe to create histograms with labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045852/using-lapply-on-a-dataframe-to-create-histograms-with-labels) and [Labels for histogram, when using “lapply”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134491/labels-for-histogram-when-using-lapply)

The `xlab = paste(colnames(u))` is the closest but the x-label in the histogram is not the right one rather a list of all of them.
Please see the image.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJbGu.png)

 

 
However, when I'm creating a similar histogram but of only one set of data in the histogram, i.e. not including `hist(i[x$rand=="A"], col=rgb(1,0,0,0.2), add=TRUE)`. It works fine.

```
mapply(hist, as.data.frame(x[,4:11]), main=colnames(x[,4:11]), xlab="score")
```

I created a example dataset, that in it´s form looks like mine, see code.

```
 Library("dplyr")
    datf <- data.frame(cbind(sample(0:100,size=150, replace=T), 
                             sample(0:100,size=150, replace=T), 
                             sample(0:100,size=150, replace=T),
                             sample(0:100,size=150, replace=T),
                             sample(0:100,size=150, replace=T),
                             sample(0:100,size=150, replace=T),
                             sample(0:100,size=150,replace=T),
                             sample(0:100,size=150, replace=T)))
    datf$rand <- sample(c("D","A"),150, replace=T, prob=c(0.45,0.45))
    datf$pid <- sample(1:150, replace=F, size=150)
    datf$gender <- sample(c("F","M"),150, replace=T, prob=c(0.35,0.65))
    datf <- datf%>%
      rename(
        BP=X1,
        GH=X2,
        VT=X3,
        MH=X4, 
        SF=X5, 
        PF=X6,
        RP=X7,
        RE=X8
      )
    datf <- datf[, c("pid","rand","gender", "BP", "GH","VT","MH", "PF" , "RP", "RE","SF")]
```

And dput()

```
structure(list(pid = c(108L, 54L, 75L, 2L), rand = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A"), gender = c("M", "M", "F", "M"), BP = c(70L, 13L, 27L, 
66L), GH = c(2L, 68L, 61L, 19L), VT = c(57L, 68L, 30L, 0L), MH = c(65L, 
69L, 21L, 47L), PF = c(100L, 38L, 70L, 60L), RP = c(77L, 27L, 
59L, 38L), RE = c(66L, 9L, 68L, 48L), SF = c(30L, 74L, 64L, 20L
)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

**This is how I would like the output to look like:**
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOjgb.png)

Would it be easier to use  ggplot? - But then how?

 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you Ronak Shah! I have now updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this is closer to what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)

datf %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = BP:SF) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(value, fill = rand) + 
  geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have to learn how to change the colors and opacity but this was so great.